# How to use loop to apply a function in several dataframes and paste the result in the specific dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, assign

I have two dataframes `AAA`, `BBB` (and will have more dataframes, so it's worth using loop)

And I have a user-defined function `V2.Scale_function`

I want to apply `V2.Scale_function` to the #21 column of `AAA` and `BBB`

I tried

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyverse")

tables = list ("AAA", "BBB")

for(table in tables){
  assign(table, get(table) %>%
           mutate(V2.Scale= apply(table[, 21], 1, V2.Scale_function)))   ### tables here has errors
}
```

Then I got an error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `V2.Scale = apply(table[, 21], 1, V2.Scale_function)`.
Caused by error in `table[, 21]`:
! incorrect number of dimensions
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I am wondering how to fix this bug. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out:

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyverse")

tables = list ("AAA", "BBB")

### should be get(table) instead of (table)
for(table in tables){
    assign(table, get(table) %>%
    mutate(V2.Scale= apply(get(table)[, 21], 1, V2.Scale_function)))   
}
```